# add new data to server using post method not working. using Reactjs and nodejs

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, express

Am not sure which method to use to send data from clientside to server using ajax. am using Post now. below is my code plz review. thanks in adavance

this is my client side code.

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "/api/addTemplateToDb",
                type: 'POST',
                data:{
                    "Name": tempName.value,
                    "Version": "1.0",
                    "Data": "{"+ tempData.value +"}"
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }.bind(this),
                error:function(result) {
                    console.log(result.responseText);
                }
            }
        );
```

this is my server side(Node) code

```
app.post('/api/addTemplateToDb', function (req, res) {

console.log(req.body.Name); })
```

am getting a output as undefined in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insert these two lines(It parses the body) in server side**

```js
var   bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```